# (Cloud) Password Tool for small group of people

Tags: password-manager

**I'm looking for a Password Manager with following features:**

- secure (I think encrypted passwords should be standard)
- easy to use (common user, graphical interface, no shell)
- synchronized
- two step authentification
- should run on windwos
- (additional) clients for iOS or Android (how much sense makes this with the 2-step-auth?)
- is used by multiple users, but one master account should be enough

In the past we used **keepass** and the db file was synced via dropbox. We got issues with the lockfile, which was autocreated every time anyone accessed the database. I thought of using a repository, but the common users aren't able to use version control.

So is there any webservice oder cloud password manager, which is trustworthy?

Thanks for your advise.

[edit: rephrased question]

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Don't forget to include what OS it should run on, or whether it should be a web-app.

Comment: Especially: why mentioning 'a group of people'? What access do you want to have each member have to what data?

Comment: I rephrased the question. is it better now? thanks for your advise

Comment: Agree with @JanDoggen. You won't have access to your team's passwords anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## Try [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/features)

It provides an easy-to-use interface with a browser plugin or mobile app:

[image: screenshot 1]
<sub>(source: [lastpass.com](https://lastpass.com/wp-content/uploads/features_1_svgn.jpg))</sub>

Has two factor authentication, syncs across devices, and allows the sharing of credentials across accounts (you can of course just create a single master account).